# htaccess how to redirect all pages in the directory to index page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect from all pages to index page in the directory.
And wrong addresses too.

```
http://site.com/directory/anyword move to http://site.com/directory/index.html
```

I did in `.htaccess RedirectMatch 301 /directory /directory/index.html`

But I need except directory/thankyou.html

It does redirect but doesn't open index.html - `resulted in too many redirects`

May be I can try with 404.

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude index.html from your match, otherwise you get an infinite loop where directory/index.html redirects to itself over and over.

Unfortunately my knowledge of writing .htaccess files is basically nonexistent so I can't provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

Mod Rewrite?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.html$
RewriteRule /directory/.+ /directory/index.html
```

Comment: Nope. if wrong address(directory/ddkdfjskdjsdkdj) it opens 404 page

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect all pages or subdirectory to the index page.,

try this-

root/.htaccess

```
enter code here

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+?/)?home/?$ $1/index.php [L,NC]
```